# .clang-format option to customize spacing

Tags: c++, clang-format

I want to configure clang-format to add space after function name and before opening parentheses only for the function definition.

```
SpaceBeforeParens: Always
```

this option put space for every if,for loop and function call.

Is there anyway to customize it to put space only when function definition not to put space in case of function call,for,if.
I need something as below.

function definition

```
  int foo () 
  {
    return 0;
  }
```

function call. (Note there is space between function name and parentheses)

```
foo();
```

Comment: can you add your current format and expected format. I cannot understand your question directly

Comment: function call should be  function();    and function defination should be function ( ) {   }

Comment: in the function definition, there is space after function name and before paranthesis. where as in function call.  there is no space between functionname and opening parenthesis.

Comment: can you add example code

Comment: @Kalana: I have updated the question, please take look on the question once again.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do that thing into only function. It also put spaces on `if`, `for`, `while` etc  but there is no wrong with put space between `if` and `()`. I suggest you to use `SpaceBeforeParens: Always` because still there is no way to do that. Hope they will update clang-format to do this kind of work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do that thing into only function.

Answer (score 0):

i just found it myself in clang documentation
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterFunction : true
```

```
true:
void foo()
{
  bar();
  bar2();
}

false:
void foo() {
  bar();
  bar2();
}
```

Comment: Op asked about spaces, not braces.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).